# Force maven to use a specific repository for extensions

Tags: maven, maven-repository

I have a maven extension added to my .mvn/extensions.xml and when I try to execute maven it tries to download it from maven central. We recently switched to internal repos and while my artifacts and plugins are downloaded from the repositories defined in the pom and not from maven central, the extensions are still being downloaded from maven central. Is there any way to instruct maven to use alternative repos when downloading extensions?

My .mvn/extensions.xml

```
<extensions xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/EXTENSIONS/1.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/EXTENSIONS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/core-extensions-1.0.0.xsd">
  <extension>
    <groupId>fr.brouillard.oss</groupId>
    <artifactId>jgitver-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.1</version>
  </extension>
</extensions>
```

Maven version: 3.8.6

Comment: Which Maven version do you use?

Comment: 3.8.6 (I also added it to the question)

Comment: Please show your settings.xml configuration how you configured to use a different repository...

Comment: I managed to solve it (see my own answer). Thanks for pointing me to the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I solved it was to add  to my settings.xml. Adding them to pom.xml doesn't work (I guess maven needs to have extensions resolved prior to loading pom.xml) and I didn't find other ways of doing it.
A workaround I also found was to comment out extensions and use dependency:get to manually download dependencies but it has it's problems too.

What I added to the ~/.m2/settings.xml

```
<mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <id>local-maven-central</id>
      <name>Maven Central</name>
      <url>URL OF OUR LOCAL central MIRROR</url>
      <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>
    <mirror>
      <id>local-maven-apache</id>
      <name>Maven Apache Mirror</name>
      <url>URL OF OUR LOCAL apache MIRROR</url>
      <mirrorOf>apache</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>
</mirrors>
```

Comment: Can you show us what do you put in your settings.xml ?

Comment: I expanded my answer to show my mirror configuration.